# Extracting Ints from a string in a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a DataFrame like below:

```
df = DataFrame("Code" => ["W01", "W12","C04"])
```

The `df.Code` column is always a 3-character string formed by 1 letter and 2 digits. I need to extract the digits (as int) to a new column lets say Code_Int. So “W01” will be 1, “W12” will be 12 and so on. This column has 180000 records with this exact pattern.

What i did so far:

Create a new column as:

```
df=insertcols!(df,4,:Code_Int=>0)
```

Tried this:

```
df[:Code_Int]=[parse(Int64,x) for x in df[!,:Code]
```

and i get

```
ArgumentError: Invalid base 10 digit 'W' in "W01"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. You only want to parse the integer component of the string (not the letter), so you should replace `parse(Int64,x)` with `parse(Int64, x[2:end])`.

If `x = "W12"`, then `x[2:end]` (or `x[2:3]`) is just `"12"`, which you can then parse as an integer.

Comment: nice ! jesus, i am dumb. Thank you very much man xD

Answer (score 1):

A probably more reliable solution than just using indexes would be to use regular expressions.

```
julia> map(x -> parse(Int64, match(r"[[:digit:]]+", x).match), df.Code)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
 12
  4
```

You can add the column to your DataFrame using

```
insertcols!(df, :Code_Int => map(x -> parse(Int64, match(r"[[:digit:]]+", x).match), df.Code))
```

or

```
df.Code_Int = map(x -> parse(Int64, match(r"[[:digit:]]+", x).match), df.Code)
```